# How to install PHP's mysql module?

Tags: php, mysql, docker

OS: `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`
I use the following commands:

`$ phpversion=7.1
$ apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common
$ add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
$ apt-get update && apt-get -y install php${phpversion} php${phpversion}-mysql php${phpversion}-gd libapache2-mod-auth-tkt`

After this, I install SMF bbs and phorum bbs, both of which are using php and mysql. Whene I run both of them, they both tell me that there is no mysql support in PHP.
I wonder how to install full mysql support in PHP, I'm not familar with PHP at all. Thanks a lot.

Supplement:
In fact, I use the same bbs code, same OS, install the same PHP version(7.1) in a Docker container, and everything works well. However, I run all of this in a real environment, it occurs some errors. I'm really confused. My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04  
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8  
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \      
    python-software-properties \  
    software-properties-common  
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php  
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install \  
    apache2 \  
    php7.1 \  
    php7.1-mysql \  
    php7.1-gd \  
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*   
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER="www-data" APACHE_RUN_GROUP="www-data" APACHE_LOG_DIR="/var/log/apache2"  
RUN rm rf /var/www/html/*  
ADD smf/ /var/www/html/  
RUN cd /var/www/html/ && chmod -R 777 *  
EXPOSE 80  

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: mysql has been removed (older/outdated library) from PHP 7.x  The new use is either mysqli (note the trailing 'i') or PDO. You can lookup both of these on PHP's site. Know that mysqli is very similar to the old mysql, but there ARE some differences.

Comment: This is dangerous: `RUN cd /var/www/html/ && chmod -R 777 *`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have the old mysql in PHP 7.x You must use mysqli or PDO. For a complete list of all the deprecated functions in PHP 7.x, [go here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7)

Comment: In fact, I use the same bbs code, same OS, install the same PHP version(7.1) in a Docker container, and everything works well. However, I run all of this in a  real environment, it occurs some errors. I'm really confused.